# How to invoke event on click on message property of AlertController of ionic?

Tags: ionic2, onclick, ionic3

```
callHelpCenter(){
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        subTitle: 'Help Center',
        message: "<p (click)='callEn()'>Phone number 12345</p>",
        buttons: ['Dismiss']
   )}
} 

callEn(){
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

As I have written above code, I want to handle the event on clicking of the message `<p>`. Tag it's showing in DOM properly but not able to call the function  `(click)='callEn()'` . So how can I handle on click of message of the custom alert in ionic?

Comment: I think it is possible to do so. Anyways the alertCtrl has 2 buttons (Yes and No) and you should call your callEn() in in yes button handler. It should work.

Comment: On button I can handle anyways agree but I am looking to call that function on the click of the message part only.

Comment: did you try something like this "<a href='javascript:callEn();'>Phone number 12345</a>"?

Comment: I tried just but this also isn't working

Comment: Make custom alertController Using Modal .